# Repeating table without repeating choice in InfoPath

Tags: microsoft-infopath

I have the following issue with a repeating table in InfoPath.

For the sections "Shareholders with 20% or more stake in a company" I have the following problem: When I choose Yes, another section opens where the user can write the name of state shareholders or involved persons in the fields.

[image: the fields]

<sup>open the image in a new tab to see it in full size</sup>

Once I then click on **Insert another entity**, that whole section is repeated, with the same choices made already before:

[image: repeated]

How do I have to alter the InfoPath file so that I can insert as many entities as I want **without** the file also repeating the choice and the text fields?